# Boost Shared Pointers and Memory Management

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I began using boost rather recently and am impressed by the functionality and APIs provided.

In using boost::shared_ptr, when I check the program with Valgrind, I found a considerable number of "Still reachable" memory leaks. As per the documentation of Valgrind, these are not a problem. However, since I used to use the standard C++ library only, I always made sure that any program written is completely free from memory leaks.

My question is, are these memory leaks something to  worry about? I tried using reset(), however it only decrements the reference count, doesn't deallocate memory. Can I safely ignore these, or any way to forcibly deallocate the memory allocated by boost::shared_ptr?

Thank you.

EDIT1:

I'm using apache thrift in this code. Further checking with valigrind, with the option --show-reachable=yes, almost all of the leak messages are similar to below:

```
==6813== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 21
==6813==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6813==    by 0x5E7A783: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==6813==    by 0x5EF524A: lh_insert (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==6813==    by 0x5E7BC17: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==6813==    by 0x5E7C268: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==6813==    by 0x5BF43C5: SSL_CTX_free (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
==6813==    by 0x4E9574F: apache::thrift::transport::SSLContext::~SSLContext() (TSSLSocket.cpp:71)
==6813==    by 0x4E95768: apache::thrift::transport::SSLContext::~SSLContext() (TSSLSocket.cpp:74)
==6813==    by 0x4E96C08:  apache::thrift::transport::TSSLSocketFactory::~TSSLSocketFactory() (sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145)
==6813==    by 0x4E96C98: apache::thrift::transport::TSSLSocketFactory::~TSSLSocketFactory() (TSSLSocket.cpp:369)
==6813==    by 0x42A986: void boost::checked_delete<apache::thrift::transport::TSSLSocketFactory>(apache::thrift::transport::TSSLSocketFactory*) (checked_delete.hpp:34)
==6813==    by 0x42ADE3: boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<apache::thrift::transport::TSSLSocketFactory>::dispose() (sp_counted_impl.hpp:78)
```

Does this mean that it is the thrift code that is leaking memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the leak?

Comment: Usually `shared_ptr` managed memory is deallocated when the reference count goes to zero. If this is not the case there might be various reasons depending on how your application uses the `shared_ptr`. Worst is you could have circular references with shared pointers in your class structures, in this case the allocated memory will never be deallocated at all AFAIK.

Comment: What @g-makulik said; the operative keyword to find a solution to that is `weak_ptr`

Comment: @FredLarson: Thanks for the suggesstions. I'll try to post a compilable sample, but it is hard to get the same scenario in a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if the memory is still reachable it's not a leak. If you define a leak as some memory you've reserved using malloc/new but you cannot release it anymore, as in

```
//this leaks since p is unreachable outside the scope
int main() {
  char * p = (char*)malloc(10);
  return 0; 
}
```

You can have a situation where your memory always grows but it's not technically a leak, e.g. you have a global list you always put things in but never put them out.
In that case the list memory is reachable and you `could` free it.

Having said that, by the call stack pasted in your question, it seems the referenced memory is some allocation done by libcrypto when destroying the thrift SSL transport.

So your shared pointer is not the problem, most probably is just buffered memory used inside libcrypto.

Comment: +1. when I trace back to the origins of the leaks they are from the libraries that I am using.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc

If `uordblks` at the start of your program are the same as those at the end, you have no leaks. since you have managed to free all the memory you have allocated.

Comment: Interesting.  Is it legitimate to call `mallinfo()` from an `atexit()` handler?